# Select dinamicos, comó puedo hacer?

Tags: php, html, formularios

tengo los siguientes códigos:

```html
<? php
$mont = date('m');
switch ($mont) {
  case 1: $cantidad_dias = 31;break;
  case 2: $cantidad_dias = 28;break;
  case 3: $cantidad_dias = 31;break;
  case 4: $cantidad_dias = 30;break;
  case 5: $cantidad_dias = 31;break;
  case 6: $cantidad_dias = 30;break;
  case 7: $cantidad_dias = 31;break;
  case 8: $cantidad_dias = 31;break;
  case 9: $cantidad_dias = 30;break;
  case 10: $cantidad_dias = 31;break;
  case 11: $cantidad_dias = 30;break;
  case 12: $cantidad_dias = 31;break;   
}
?>
```

El fragmento anterior de php va con lo siguiente en la misma página

```html
<select name="dia">
        <?php
        for ($i=1; $i<=$cantidad_dias; $i++) {
            if ($i == date('d'))
                echo '<option value="'.$i.'" selected>'.$i.'</option>';
            else if($i < date('d'))
                echo '';
            else 
              echo '<option value="'.$i.'">'.$i.'</option>';

        }
        ?>
</select>

<select name="mes">
        <?php
        for ($i=1; $i<=12; $i++) {
            if ($i == date('m'))
                echo '<option value="'.$i.'" selected>'.$i.'</option>';            
            else if ($i < date('m'))
              echo '';
            else
                echo '<option value="'.$i.'">'.$i.'</option>';
        }
        ?>
</select>

<select name="ano">
        <?php
        for($i=date('Y'); $i>=date('Y'); $i--){
            if ($i == date('Y'))
                echo '<option value="'.$i.'" selected>'.$i.'</option>';
            else
                echo '<option value="'.$i.'">'.$i.'</option>';
        }
        ?>
</select>
```

Ahora un poco de jquery

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#mes").on('change', function () {
        $("#mes option:selected").each(function () {
            elegido=$(this).val(); alert(elegido);
            $.post("../select_mes.php", { elegido: elegido }, function(data){
                $("#dia").html(data);
            });   
        });
   });
});
```

Y select_mes.php

```html
<?php 

$mont = $_POST['elegido'];
switch ($mont) {
  case 1: $cantidad_dias = 31;break;
  case 2: $cantidad_dias = 28;break;
  case 3: $cantidad_dias = 31;break;
  case 4: $cantidad_dias = 30;break;
  case 5: $cantidad_dias = 31;break;
  case 6: $cantidad_dias = 30;break;
  case 7: $cantidad_dias = 31;break;
  case 8: $cantidad_dias = 31;break;
  case 9: $cantidad_dias = 30;break;
  case 10: $cantidad_dias = 31;break;
  case 11: $cantidad_dias = 30;break;
  case 12: $cantidad_dias = 31;break;   
}
echo $cantidad_dias;
```

Son tres select, **día**, **mes** y **año**, lo que deseo es que al seleccionar el mes 5 u otro en adelante al mes que me muestra, me carguen los días correspondientes a ese mes, para ello escribi algo de jquery pero no me hace lo que requiero, el cual sería seleccionar cualquier mes y me ocupe o muestre los días que le corresponde a este mes, ahora que lo publico, marca 19/4/2019.

¿Se puede hacer?,¿Qué estara mal? ¿Qué se les ocurre?.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que esto te ayudara

```
<div class="form-group">
     <label for="">Dia Inicio</label>
     <input type="date" name="dia1" value="<?php echo date("Y-m-d");?>" required class="form-control" max="<?php echo $hoy ?>">
</div>
```

[image: aquí se muestra el resultado]

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, pero  necesito los select.

Answer (score 0):

**En tu codigo php agrega una id en tus tags para identificarlas 
este es el caso de selector del años.**

```
<select name="ano" id="selectAnio">
        <?php //2019 ; 2019>=2019 ; 2018
        for($i=date('Y'); $i>=date('Y'); $i--){
            if ($i == date('Y'))
                echo '<option value="'.$i.'" selected>'.$i.'</option>';
            else
                echo '<option value="'.$i.'">'.$i.'</option>';
        }
        ?>
</select>
```

**en el caso del mes agregarle un evento**

```
<select name="mes" id="selectMes" onchange="cargaDias()">
        <?php
        for ($i=1; $i<=12; $i++) {
            if ($i == date('m'))
                echo '<option value="'.$i.'" selected>'.$i.'</option>';            
            else if ($i < date('m'))
              echo '';
            else
                echo '<option value="'.$i.'">'.$i.'</option>';
        }
        ?>
</select>
```

**en el dia dejarlo de esta manera**

```
<select name="dia" id="selectDia">

</select>
```

**crear un script js**

```
<script>
function cargaDias(){
var selectAnio = $("#selectAnio").val();
var selectMes = $("#selectMes").val();
var dias = new Date(selectAnio, selectMes, 0).getDate();

 $("#selectDia").html('');

 var html_ = '<option></option>';
 for(int i = 1;i<=dias ; i++){
   selectDia +=  '<option>'+i+'</option>';
 }

$("#selectDia").html(html_);

}
</script>
```

Comment: Gracias, lo probe, pero no me realizaba cambios a los días al seleccionar el mes, no se porque?, hice todo como lo explicaba.